# How to inject personal script in HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to update my research group's webpage, and trying to write some scripts. The problem is the access we were granted is very limited and the HTML editor on the page administration (codemagic) strips away any script, styles, classes that I try implementing.

Is there a way to inject a script into my own basic HTML page to get it to do what i want?

this is the environment i am working with.
[snap of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgwfP.png)

one i hit the update for the codemagic it will remove the script tag, i can't write any functions in there

update: i have successfully been able to add the script. and when i use the document.scripts.length it shows me the updated number of scripts sections.
my problem now is that the functions inside the scripts don't execute

Comment: Probably not, but you can try embedding an iframe, maybe?

Comment: Whoever is managing your server probably has reasons to remove scripts and styles. You can talk to them and explain why you need these, or you can host your page elsewhere. Don't waste your time looking for a technical solution to a problem which is non-technical by nature.

Comment: what have your tried? Please remember that SO suggests a minimum reproducible example.

Comment: What is it you are trying to add? PErhaps we can try to do it without a script.

Answer (score 0):

YES. When you use javascripts createElement function it will not show. Why? The element is not technically "on" the html file. You need to use the appendChild function to make it show. For example:

```
    function makeElement() {
        var t = document.createElement("DIV");
        element.appendChild(t); // don't forget to define element
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
function appendHTML() {
    var s= document.createElement('script');
    s.innerHTML = 'alert("hello")';
    document.body.appendChild(s);
}
appendHTML();
```

Or, if you need a script with more than 1 lines, then do it like this:

```
function appendHTML() {
    var s= document.createElement('script');
    s.innerHTML = 'alert("hello 1")'+
                  'alert("hello 2")'+
                  'alert("hello 3")';
    document.body.appendChild(s);
}
appendHTML();
```

> Make sure you use it responsibly.

Comment: thank you all for the responses, but i can't use any of that as i can't actually write any scripts to start with. so i can't write any functions at the time being.
is there a way to createElement without assigning it to a variable yet have a handler for it to append children ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't write scripts, could you make a link element?

```
    <link rel="" src="" />
```

This can link scripts into your HTML document. If you can't link scripts then your server does not support javascript or HTML. It would help if you explain what you are using to host it.